# HighCharts does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument in ASP.Net MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I installed HighCharts into my MVC project:

`Install-Package DotNet.HighCharts`

...and tried to run a basic pie chart demo.  However, I get a message in VS2012Express:

`bm.Controllers.Highcharts' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments`

The line it doesn't like is: `Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")`

`new Highcharts("chart")` is underlined in Red, and is the only error noted.  My controller code is below.

Can anyone see whay may be causing this error (the demos work fine - but I can't see any different in the web.config files etc?

Thank you,

Mark

```
using DotNet.Highcharts.Enums;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Options;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Drawing;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers;
using DotNet.Highcharts.Samples.Models;
using Point = DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Point;


namespace bm.Controllers
{
public class ChartController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Chart/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult DataLabels()
    {
        string[] categories = new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
        object[] tokioData = new object[] { 7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6 };
        object[] londonData = new object[] { 3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8 };

        Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
            .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Line })
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Monthly Average Temperature" })
            .SetSubtitle(new Subtitle { Text = "Source: WorldClimate.com" })
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = categories })
            .SetYAxis(new YAxis { Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Temperature (°C)" } })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Enabled = true, Formatter = @"function() { return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+ this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C'; }" })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
            {
                Line = new PlotOptionsLine
                {
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsLineDataLabels
                    {
                        Enabled = true
                    },
                    EnableMouseTracking = false
                }
            })
            .SetSeries(new[]
                       {
                           new Series { Name = "Tokyo", Data = new Data(tokioData) },
                           new Series { Name = "London", Data = new Data(londonData) }
                       });

        return View(chart);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Hi - for info, I changed the line to: DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart") - nd it's working now!!

Comment: Nice one, please could you mark it as the answer by selecting the green tick? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is picking up the wrong HighChart class in your application.

If you change the following:

```
Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
```

To this:

```
DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")
```

It should work.

You must have another class with the namespace of bm.Controllers.Highcharts

Answer (score 0):

add below dll to your codes:

> using DotNet.Highcharts;

then you can use this:

> Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")